Question on Variance Inflation Factor (Variables seem correlated but VIF is not high)
I am trying to run the following regressions

Preferences for redistribution = debt/financial_assets + debt/realestate_assets + someothercontrols + e. 
2. Preferences for redistribution = debt/financial_assets + financial_assets + someothercontrols + e.

The first equation has two ratio variables with the same numerator. 
The second equation has a ratio variable and a level variable which is the denominator of that ratio variable.
Intuitively, it makes sense that both equations might somewhat be problematic because the variables are correlated. But when I calculate the VIF, at most it's 1.5-2. Which I think it means they are still moderately correlated but not so problematic. 
Does this mean running those regressions are fine? Or should I still follow my intuition and not include both of them in the same model.

What's the correlation?
